# Ionic ngCamera plugin return invalid FILE_URI

Tags: ionic-framework

**My controller:**

```
$scope.takePicture = function () {

var options = {
  destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
  sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
};

$cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageURI) {
  console.log("imageURI " + imageURI);
  $scope.imgURI = imageURI;
}, function (err) {
  // error
});
```

}

Is not returning a valid FILE_URI, see log example:

```
imageURI iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAgAAAAIACAYAAAD0eNT6AAAABmJLR0QAegC3AB5wP5bnAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAAB3RJTUUH4AgGEx0wCF7kpgAAIABJREFUeNrsvXlwnOd95/l53qtvAI37IAiA903RFK2LsnXbli0lju04ceQ4k62NZ7JJZSa7tVuV3a3MHzuzNX9sdrbiVHZrk9kZO4ozOWw5liXbuk+KkiiKl0ASJAGCuO++u9/jefaPPggKIAlSJEVRz6cKhaMb3W+/bz/9+/7ORwAKjUaj0Wg0nyoMfQo0Go1Go9ECQKPRaDQajRYAGo1Go9FotADQaDQajUajBYBGo9FoNBotADQajUaj0WgBoNFoNBqNRgsAjUa{...big string...}
```

I don't know whats is happening

Comment: looks like base64-encoded stuff

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try with URL?

```js
 var options = {
        quality: 100,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
        allowEdit: true,
        encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        targetWidth: 200,
        targetHeight: 200,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: false
      };

      $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options)
       .then(function (imageData) {
          var image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
          //image has the URL
        }, function(error) {
          console.log(error)
        });
```